# Hadoop job formulation, passing ArrayList<String> to Mapper()

Tags: java, hadoop, mapper

Trying to formulate a Hadoop job that is different than the normal Word Count example. My input data is of the form:

```
makePush,1964
makePush,459
makePush,357
opAdd,2151
opAdd,257
opStop,135
```

I'd like to pass these to the `Mapper()`, and subsequently the `Reducer()` functions, but I'm having trouble with the specification, i.e.

```
Mapper<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>
```

So then, for example, `opAdd` would be a `KEYIN`, and `257` would be a `VALUEIN`. Subsequently the sum of all `opAdd` would be a `KEYOUT` and the sum of the associated numbers would be `VALUEOUT`, that makes sense doesn't it?

However, how to implement this programmatically? It seems to me it's not so different from the Word Count example in theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for example, opAdd would be a KEYIN, and 257 would be a VALUEIN

No, the Key would be a LongWritable, which is the offset marker in the file to designate where the current map task is reading the file.

The Value would be Text, which would be the entire line of `opAdd,257`, which you would `toString().split(",")` to separate the data

Comment: aha- I think I see what you mean- since different nodes will read the file at different places is it?

Comment: Correct. The LongWritable is serialized between all the map tasks so they know where they start reading the file lines.

Comment: do know how I can `System.out.println("*something about intermediate process state for debugging*")` in Hadoop- do I need to use this `log4j`?

Comment: Yes. Log4j. Something like `private static final Logger LOG = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(MyMapper.class);`, then you can `LOG.info("something")`

Comment: but then where can I read the logs? I tried to do it like this https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/c244c31b8e4e55b338b5ab96506d2009 but it didn't work or I can;t find them- I was searching in `:8088/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-namenode.log`

Comment: The logs are collected into the YARN container that is running your task, not the namenode

Comment: You need to navigate to `:8088/cluster/app/application_{appId}`, then select the Logs link towards the bottom right... And the job needs to be actively running. This is assuming you started a jar with `yarn jar` rather than `hadoop jar`

Comment: I've been doing `javac -cp ${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}:commons-io-2.5.jar OpcodeCount.java`, `jar cf oc.jar OpcodeCount*.class`,`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar oc.jar OpcodeCount /input_1 /output_6` - so you're saying there's another way to make that `jar` file? also- since it's just the word count job- it's over so quickly, maybe I should throw a sleep in there or something to give me time to check it out?

Comment: I typically use Maven/Gradle to make jar files, but that works... I was simply referring to the `bin/hadoop jar` piece.

Comment: There is a JobHistory server, but you probably need to configure/start that process

Comment: that makes sense- but then - I just ran it in the way you sugest with `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/yarn jar oc.jar OpcodeCount /input_1 /output_8`, but there's no way I can log the log to somewhere to examine it after the job terminates?

Comment: you mean this guy I think `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh stop historyserver`

Comment: Yup, that's it. Obviously use `start` rather than `stop`. And the default port for that is `:50030`

Comment: man I started it but I don't see it there at `master:50030` its just a 404 or somethng

Comment: so- I think it's now `19888 `, went there- and all of my jobs are there- but still no logs

Comment: Right, sorry, was looking at a different port. Not sure why you wouldn't be able to see anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155713/discussion-between-cricket-007-and-s-matthew-english).